# Proof for $\alpha \times \beta \cong \alpha \otimes \beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I need to prove the following theorem:

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinals. Then $\alpha \times \beta \cong \alpha \otimes \beta$, where $\alpha \times \beta$ is in anti-lexicographic order.

I have come up with one proof, and I would like to get it validated.

Proof. The case $\alpha = \boldsymbol{0}$ is trivial, as $\alpha \times \beta = \alpha \otimes \beta = \boldsymbol{0}$. We shall assume $\alpha \neq \boldsymbol{0}$ in our following argument. Suppose that $\delta$ is an ordinal. Fix an ordinal $\alpha \neq \boldsymbol{0}$ and define the following set:
\begin{equation*}
A = \left\{\beta \in \delta: \alpha \times \beta \cong \alpha \otimes \beta\right\}.
\end{equation*}
First consider the case $\beta = \boldsymbol{0}$. As
\begin{equation*}
\alpha \times \boldsymbol{0} = \alpha \otimes \boldsymbol{0} = \boldsymbol{0},
\end{equation*}
it is obvious that $\boldsymbol{0} \in A$.

Next assume that $\gamma \subseteq A$ and $\gamma \neq \emptyset$. That is, for any $\theta \in \gamma$, $\alpha \times \theta \cong \alpha \otimes \theta$. Suppose $\gamma = {\theta_{0}}^{+}$ for some $\theta_{0} \in \gamma$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\alpha \times \gamma = \alpha \times {\theta_{0}}^{+} = \alpha \times \left(\theta_{0} \cup \left\{\theta_{0}\right\}\right) = \left(\alpha \times \theta_{0}\right) \cup \left(\alpha \times \left\{\theta_{0}\right\}\right),
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\alpha \otimes \gamma = \alpha \otimes {\theta_{0}}^{+} = \left(\alpha \otimes \theta_{0}\right) \oplus \alpha.
\end{equation*}
Using our induction hypothesis, we have $\alpha \times \theta_{0} \cong \alpha \otimes \theta_{0}$. Thus, there is an order-isomorphism $f_{1}: \alpha \otimes \theta_{0} \to \alpha \times \theta_{0}$. Next, assume that $\lambda \in \alpha$. We immediately have $\left(\alpha \otimes \theta_{0}\right) \oplus \lambda \not\in \alpha \otimes \theta_{0}$. There is an order-isomorphism $f_{2}: \left\{\left(\alpha \otimes \theta_{0}\right) \oplus \lambda: \lambda \in \alpha\right\} \to \alpha \times \left\{\theta_{0}\right\}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\forall \lambda \in \alpha, f_{2}\left(\alpha \otimes \theta_{0} \oplus \lambda\right) = \left(\lambda,\theta_{0}\right).
\end{equation*}
Define a function $f_{3}: \left(\alpha \otimes \theta_{0}\right) \oplus \alpha \to \left(\alpha \times \theta_{0}\right) \cup \left(\alpha \times \left\{\theta_{0}\right\}\right)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
f_{3}\left(x\right) = 
\begin{cases}
f_{1}\left(x\right),\ x \in \alpha \otimes \theta_{0}\\
f_{2}\left(x\right),\ x \in \left(\alpha \otimes \theta_{0}\right) \oplus \alpha \textrm{ and } x \not\in \alpha \otimes \theta_{0}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation*}
In this way, we have defined an order-isomorphism $f_{3}: \alpha \otimes \gamma \to \alpha \times \gamma$, and we have $\alpha \otimes \gamma \cong \alpha \times \gamma$. Thus, we may conclude that $\gamma \subseteq A$ leads to $\gamma \in A$ when $\gamma$ is a successor ordinal.

Now suppose that $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal. Then according to definition, we have
\begin{equation*}
\alpha \otimes \gamma = \bigcup\left\{\alpha \otimes \lambda: \lambda \in \gamma\right\},
\end{equation*}
and further,
\begin{equation*}
\alpha \times \gamma = \alpha \times \bigcup{\gamma} = \bigcup\left\{\alpha \times \lambda: \lambda \in \gamma\right\}.
\end{equation*}
According to our induction hypothesis, for any $\lambda \in \gamma$, we have $\alpha \otimes \lambda \cong \alpha \times \lambda$. Thus, there is a order-isomorphism $f_{\lambda}: \alpha \otimes \lambda \to \alpha \times \lambda$ for every $\lambda \in \gamma$. We may define the functions so that $f_{\lambda_{1}} = f_{\lambda_{2}}\vert_{\lambda_{1}}$, if $\lambda_{1} \in \lambda_{2} \in \gamma$ (so that $\lambda_{1} \subseteq \lambda_{2}$). Define a set
\begin{equation*}
g = \left\{f_{\lambda} \in \mathscr{P}\left(\left(\alpha \otimes \gamma\right) \times \left(\alpha \times \lambda\right)\right): \lambda \in \gamma\right\},
\end{equation*}
and further another set
\begin{equation*}
f = \bigcup g.
\end{equation*}
We first argue that $f$ is a function. If it is not, then there exist at least two 2-tuples $\left(x_{0},y_{1}\right), \left(x_{0},y_{2}\right) \in f$ with $y_{1} \neq y_{2}$. Then there are $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2} \in \gamma$ such that $\lambda_{1} \neq \lambda_{2}$ and $\left(x_{0},y_{1}\right) \in f_{\lambda_{1}}$ and $\left(x_{0},y_{2}\right) \in f_{\lambda_{2}}$. Without loss of generality, we assume $\lambda_{1} \in \lambda_{2}$. As $f_{\lambda_{1}} = f_{\lambda_{2}}\vert_{\lambda_{1}}$, we have $y_{1} = y_{2}$. This contradicts our assumption for $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$. Thus, $f$ is a function.

We then argue that $\operatorname{Domain}\left(f\right) = \alpha \otimes \gamma$ and $\operatorname{Range}\left(f\right) = \alpha \times \gamma$. This step is straightforward, as
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Domain}\left(f\right) = \bigcup\left\{\alpha \otimes \lambda: \lambda \in \gamma\right\} = \alpha \otimes \gamma,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Range}\left(f\right) = \bigcup\left\{\alpha \times \lambda: \lambda \in \gamma\right\} = \alpha \times \bigcup \gamma = \alpha \times \gamma.
\end{equation*}

We shall finally argue that $f$ is an order-isomorphism. Assume $\theta_{1} \in \theta_{2} \in \alpha \otimes \gamma$. Then there is $\lambda_{0} \in \gamma$ such that $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} \in \alpha \otimes \lambda_{0}$. As $f_{\lambda_{0}}\left(\theta_{1}\right) < f_{\lambda_{0}}\left(\theta_{2}\right)$, we have $f_{\lambda}\left(\theta_{1}\right) < f_{\lambda}\left(\theta_{2}\right)$. We conclude that $\alpha \otimes \gamma \cong \alpha \times \gamma$, and that $\gamma \subseteq A$ leads to $\gamma \in A$ when $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal.

Finally, we have $A = \delta$, according to transfinite induction for ordinals.